# git how to store different files in archive from 2 branches

Tags: git

I am new to GIT, learned few tutorials and I have created master branch and an other working branch where i am working on a task.

I have created this on my local machine. My client dont have git or any thing. So when I have to update the server. I do create a rar file with all the updated files and upload them.

I am working on a task (branch A) and uploaded that to server. Later client asked me to roll back (which is master branch). Suppose the changed files are a,b,c,d in new branch (which I had uploaded) and there are A to Z files on master. I switched back to master branch. Now I need to get old a,b,c,d files so I can upload them to server.

I have installed Tortoise GIT and also GIT GUI. I have checked compare branch option of Tortoise GIT and it shows me the files which are modified. When I export that it only saves the file name

My question is. How can I get the different files from 2 branches, in a zip/rar archive keeping the folder structure intact.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `git diff --name-only master working_branch` to get the names of the files that have changed and pipe that through your favorite archiver.

One problem remains, you cannot easily delete files from the remote side. The option `--diff-filter` might help with that, i.e. `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D master working_branch` would list the files that have been deleted in working_branch.

EDIT: It depends on what archiver you want to use. The following seems to work for Cygwin's [zip package](http://cygwin.com/packages/zip/):

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM master working_branch | zip patch.zip -@
```

The patch will contain added and modified files.

Comment: Thank you for commands, could you please also tell me how i can add them in archive with full directory structure.

Comment: Your edit is good, but how can I get old version of modified files in the zip :) Master have A to Z files, branch has A, B, C updated. i need A, B, C from Master to restore a backup or roll back the files

Comment: if old == master then checkout master and play around with the various `--diff-filter` options (probably `--diff-filter=M`).

Answer (score 0):

```
git archive --format=zip -o diff_archive.zip HEAD `git diff --name-only master..HEAD`
```